# Is there any difference between Map<String,Object> and Java object after json serialization?

Tags: java, json, serialization

Suppose I have an object and a map. The map has the same key-value pair as the property of the Object. I wander after json serialization, are they same?  I have write some test and the result is they are same, but I'm not sure if all the cases are same.

Generally they have the following pattern.

```
Class ClassA{
   ClassB b;
   ClassC c;
}

Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap();
map.put("b",objectB);
map.put("c",objectC);
```

Comment: Nope not the same in any way.  Think about it - when the map is serialized - the "key" and the "value" need to be serialized (because a map can have ANY key/value mapping [or the right types].  When the ClassA is serialized - only the values needs to be serialized because java knows there's a b property and a c property - it's not any random things.

Comment: I mean serialized to json. With jackson or gson.

Comment: Even if represented the same way - deserializing won't give both ways back unless you force it to (how does jackson know you need a ClassB for "b" unless you tell it somehow...)??

Comment: I don't care about deserialization. I'am just asking are they same after serialization.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question correctly, you ask if `JsonSerialisation(objectA)` is equal to `JsonSerialisation(map)`

If so, and if you use the same serialization config, yes they will be always the same from a json perspective. Meaning that the order of the properties can be different but it will still be the same json.

An example of a return can be :

```
{
    "b": "jsonRepresentationOfObjectB",
    "c": "jsonRepresentationOfObjectC"
}
```

or

```
{
    "c": "jsonRepresentationOfObjectC",
    "b": "jsonRepresentationOfObjectB"
}
```

These 2 results are considered the equal.